# Apache poi formula evaluation for range based

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi, xlsx

We're trying to evaluate xlsx formulas using poi in java maven project, but the output values are repetitive in case of a formula having a range or array.

Below is expected vs poi output :

**Expected output**

[image: Expected output]

**poi output**

[image: poi output]

Column J and K doesn't have any formula cells.
Column L and M have formula cells dependent on J and K data.

Here's formula defined in 7 rows of column J and K :

```
Column J :
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J6)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J6))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J7)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J7))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J8)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J8))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J9)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J9))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J10)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J10))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J11)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J11))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J12)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J12))))

Column K :
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K6)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K6))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K7)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K7))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K8)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K8))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K9)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K9))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K10)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K10))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K11)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K11))))
=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K12)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K12))))
```

If we compare the images above (Expected vs poi output), then we see that poi gives incorrect results and repeat the items in J and K, whereas MS excel is able to calculate correctly.

Tried formula evaluator `evaluateAll` and `evaluateFormulaCell`. Doesn't yield correct results.
Tried with `evaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues();` and    `evaluator.notifySetFormula(cell);`
This looks like that poi is not supporting these formulas.
XSSFWorkBook is used.

```java
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    // some code in between, loops etc
    if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
        evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);    
    }
```

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>            
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Posts on stackoverflow get nothing from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that Apache POI not provides all functions for usage as `ArrayFunction`. In that special case, the [Excel function ROW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) is represented by the `Java` function [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.RowFunc](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_4/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/RowFunc.java?view=markup) which is not ready to run in array context.

That could be changed by changing the code of that `Java` function. That code needs to consider "If reference is a range of cells, and if ROW is entered as a vertical array, ROW returns the row numbers of reference as a vertical array.". My function `RowFuncArrayReady` does that.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.RefEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ValueEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval;

/**
 * Implementation for the Excel function ROW ready for usage as ArrayFunction
 */
public final class RowFuncArrayReady implements Function, ArrayFunction {
    @Override
    public ValueEval evaluate(ValueEval[] args, int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex) {
        if (args.length > 1) {
            return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID;
        }
        if (args.length == 0) {
            return new NumberEval(srcRowIndex + 1.);
        } else {
            return evaluate(srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex, args[0]);
        }
    }
        
    public ValueEval evaluate(int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex, ValueEval arg0) {
        int rnum;
        if (arg0 instanceof AreaEval) {
            rnum = ((AreaEval)arg0).getFirstRow();
        } else if (arg0 instanceof RefEval) {
            rnum = ((RefEval)arg0).getRow();
        } else {
            // anything else is not valid argument
            return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID;
        }
        return new NumberEval(rnum + 1.);
    }
    
    @Override
    public ValueEval evaluateArray(ValueEval[] args, int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex) {
        if (args.length > 1) {
            return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID;
        }
        if (args.length == 0) {
            return new NumberEval(srcRowIndex + 1.);
        } else if (args[0] instanceof AreaEval) {
            return evaluateAreaEval((AreaEval)args[0], srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex);
        } else if (args[0] instanceof RefEval) {
            return evaluate(srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex, (RefEval)args[0]);
        } else {
            // anything else is not valid argument
            return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID;
        }
    }   
    
    private ValueEval evaluateAreaEval(AreaEval ae, int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex) {
        int w1, w2, h1, h2;
        int a1FirstCol = 0, a1FirstRow = 0;
        w1 = ae.getWidth();
        h1 = ae.getHeight();
        a1FirstCol = ae.getFirstColumn();
        a1FirstRow = ae.getFirstRow();
        w2 = 1;
        h2 = 1;
        int width = Math.max(w1, w2);
        int height = Math.max(h1, h2);
        ValueEval[] vals = new ValueEval[height * width];
        int idx = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
                vals[idx++] = evaluate(srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex, ae.offset(i, i, j, j));
            }
        }
        if (vals.length == 1) {
            return vals[0];
        }
        return new CacheAreaEval(srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex, srcRowIndex + height - 1, srcColumnIndex + width - 1, vals);
    }
        
}
```

To make that new function the default representation of Excel's ROW function, it needs to be in `Function[] functions` array of [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.FunctionEval](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_4/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/eval/FunctionEval.java?view=markup) at index 8. In following code the method `prepareFunctionEval` will do that when called as `prepareFunctionEval(8, new RowFuncArrayReady());`.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ExcelEvaluateROWFormulaAsArray  {
     
 static void prepareFunctionEval(int pos, org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Function function) throws Exception {
  java.lang.reflect.Field _functions = Class.forName("org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.FunctionEval").getDeclaredField("functions");
  _functions.setAccessible(true); 
  org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Function[] functions = (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Function[])_functions.get(null); 
  functions[pos] = function;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  prepareFunctionEval(8, new RowFuncArrayReady());
   
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelUsingRowFormulaInArrayContext.xlsx"));
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); 
  
  evaluator.setDebugEvaluationOutputForNextEval(true);  
 
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    if (CellType.FORMULA == cell.getCellType()) {
     System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
     CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
     System.out.println(cellValue);
    }
   }
  }
  
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

My `ExcelUsingRowFormulaInArrayContext.xlsx` looks like so:

[image]

Note, the formulas `{=IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J6)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J6))))}` are array formulas entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. Apache POI is not able evaluating the new dynamic array formulas and spilled array behavior of Excel 365.

My `ExcelEvaluateROWFormulaAsArray` then prints:

```
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J6)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J6))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue ["Text 1"]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K6)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K6))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [1.0]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J7)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J7))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue ["Text 2"]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K7)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K7))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [2.0]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J8)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J8))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue ["Text 3"]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K8)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K8))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [3.0]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J9)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J9))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue ["Text 4"]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K9)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K9))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [4.0]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J10)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J10))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue ["Text 5"]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K10)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K10))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [5.0]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J11)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J11))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [""]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K11)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K11))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [""]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(J12)-5,"",INDEX(J:J,SMALL(IF(J$6:J$62<>"",ROW(J$6:J$62)),ROWS(J$6:J12))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [""]
IF(COUNTIF($J$6:$J$62,"?*")<ROW(K12)-5,"",INDEX(K:K,SMALL(IF(K$6:K$62<>"",ROW(K$6:K$62)),ROWS(K$6:K12))))
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [""]
```

That is the same as Excel evaluates.

To check what Apache POI Java function representations of Excel functions are ready to work in array context, there is no other way than to have a look into the source code. All such code is in https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_4/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/ and sub directories. Named functions are in /functions or /atp sub-directory.

But also operands sometimes needs to be `ArrayFunction`s. Most operands are in /eval sub-directory. For example `UnaryPlusEval` is array context ready. So `+A1:A10` will work in array context. But `ConcatEval` is not. So `A1:A10&B1:B10` will not work  in array context.

But there are also functions where the function in array context simply is not documented somewhere. For example for [COUNTIF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) it is simply unclear what shall happen if used like `COUNTIF($B$69:B69, $D$6:$D$62)` in array context. How shall the array in `What do you want to look for?` be handled? Microsoft do not tell something about that. So all one can do is to check what Excel does in such a case and then trying to program Excel's behavior using Java. That's very challenging and error prone. So I doubt someone will do this. I suspect not even Microsoft knows exactly what funny formula solutions Excel users have found, especially using the array context. So if someone needs those funny formula solutions, then this one should use the real Excel application.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer @Alex.
The change that you suggested, will this be added in future releases of poi ?

Comment: @Shaurya: Forgot one code. `class ExcelEvaluateROWFormulaAsArray`. Now it is provided too. And I don't know what will be added in future releases of poi.

Comment: I tried the above approach and it does work for the formulas in the original question.
But this still fails for more complex formulas where range is used.
The formula is  :  


=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((COUNTIF($B$69:B69, $D$6:$D$62)=0)*ISNUMBER($D$6:$D$62), $D$6:$D$62, "A"), 1), INDEX($D$6:$D$62, MATCH(SMALL(IF(ISTEXT($D$6:$D$62)*(COUNTIF(B69:$B$69, $D$6:$D$62)=0), COUNTIF($D$6:$D$62, "<"&$D$6:$D$62), ""), 1), IF(ISTEXT($D$6:$D$62), COUNTIF($D$6:$D$62, "<"&$D$6:$D$62), ""), 0)))

Comment: So for functions like INDEX, ISTEXT etc also we will have to write these custom fixes.
How can we check which function supports array usage and which does not ?

Comment: @Shaurya:  INDEX and ISTEXT is not the problem but the very special undocumented usage of `COUNTIF` is. See my supplement to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. This was really helpful.

Comment: As an alternate to poi, we're now using aspose.cell library. It's actually providing the correct results.
@Axel, 
Do you know if there is any drawback using aspose compared to poi ? It is giving correct output as excel does.

Comment: @Shaurya:  Any drawback except that Aspose is not free software as Apache POI is? No, not that I know of.

Comment: Yes it's not free.. We procured the license for aspose nuget .net , since we require these excel evaluations for a production grade application.
Hopefully poi will have these fixes in future releases.
Thanks !